# How to print AssesrtionError cause Python?

Tags: python, pytest

In my code, I'm getting Assertion error. I try to catch it and print out the cause but all I see is "FAILED".

How to get the actual data?

```
 try:       
            row = self.find_row_by_text('Something')
            assert row.status == 'OK'
            assert row.error_message == ''
 except AssertionError as e:
            LOGGER.info('\n Error is: ' + str(e))
```

Comment: what do you expect to see?

Comment: What is the traceback error message?

Comment: @Psytho in case of AssertionError - what went wrong. What actual values failed the test.

Comment: ``assert`` doesn't say you what went wrong unless you tell it to do so

Comment: Well, if you catch the error you won't get the proper error printout from pytest.

Comment: is this code in a test case? the question is tagged with `pytest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
# Making this a minimal reproducible example
class self:
    @classmethod
    def find_row_by_text(self, s):
        return row


class row:
    status="FAILED"
    error_message="something"


try:
    row = self.find_row_by_text('Something')
    assert row.status == 'OK', "row.status is not 'OK'"
    assert row.error_message == '', "row.error_message is not ''"
except AssertionError as e:
    print('\n Error is: ' + str(e))
```

output:

```
Error is: Status not OK
```

However it is probably better to raise errors:

```
row = self.find_row_by_text('Something')

if row.status != "OK":
    raise ValueError("row.status must equal OK")
```

Unless you actually want to use the optimizations that assert uses, when requested, at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You must define error messages in your asserts. Otherwise there are none.

```
try:       
    row = self.find_row_by_text('Something')
    assert row.status == 'OK', "Status is not OK."
    assert row.error_message == '', "Error message is not empty."
except AssertionError as e:
    LOGGER.info('\n Error is: ' + str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

When we raise an assert error, we also need to define the error message with the statement. Otherwise, Python treats the message as an empty text.
Syntax

```py
assert expression, message
```

```py
try:       
    row = self.find_row_by_text('Something')
    assert row.status == 'OK', "Error in row.staus statement"
    assert row.error_message == '', "Error in row.error_message statement"
except AssertionError as e:
    LOGGER.info('\n Error is: ' + str(e))
```